# Stacked-area with date format at x-axis on Gnuplot

Tags: date, graph, gnuplot

I have created graphs using filledcurves. Now, the graphs looks bad because long range of data. 
This is my data:

```
        a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i
201312  49  26  34  30  14  25  9   4   1
201311  38  22  47  30  9   9   4   3   1
201310  44  24  43  38  9   14  5   7   0
201309  65  18  33  39  15  12  4   5   1
201308  42  31  44  30  5   11  0   2   2
201307  58  27  35  29  8   4   2   4   2
201306  30  22  15  17  2   6   3   4   0
201305  61  52  20  16  11  12  2   3   0
201304  62  60  33  18  13  9   5   6   0
201303  43  53  49  27  9   11  7   0   0
201302  31  30  42  27  10  8   4   2   0
201301  42  30  20  47  9   13  3   2   1
201212  26  19  39  24  9   11  0   0   0
201211  26  26  30  28  1   2   0   2   1
201210  55  46  34  30  13  5   0   2   1
201209  56  31  27  28  27  13  2   4   1
201208  48  75  38  46  22  10  0   1   0
201207  60  56  37  47  19  11  2   1   0
201206  60  41  37  28  17  12  5   1   0
201205  49  43  38  46  15  16  2   2   0
201204  43  50  36  33  4   7   3   0   2
201203  49  63  35  43  16  7   1   2   0
201202  43  59  59  52  16  13  3   4   1
201201  51  44  30  37  20  9   4   1   0
201112  50  38  36  36  8   2   3   1   1
201111  75  35  30  36  16  7   3   3   1
201110  68  53  41  27  11  15  1   2   1
201109  68  46  48  47  16  19  4   0   1
201108  45  41  20  36  17  10  1   0   0
201107  48  34  30  24  13  7   3   3   1
201106  49  29  24  25  5   6   0   3   0
201105  45  35  21  37  1   7   2   1   0
201104  53  35  23  18  4   6   1   5   1
201103  58  42  20  18  6   4   1   0   4
201102  54  32  19  20  4   10  0   2   0
201101  42  41  21  28  3   6   1   2   1
```

and this is my gnuplot file:

```
set terminal postscript eps color font 20
set xtics 1 out
set tics front
#set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
set key below autotitle columnheader
set ylabel "Count"
set xlabel "across time"

set output 't1.eps'
set title "t1-Across time of Aspects"
set xtics 1
plot for [i=10:2:-1] \
"< awk 'NR==1 {print \"year\",$".(i-1)."} NR>=2 {for (i=2; i<=".i."; i++) \
{sum+= $i} {print $1, sum; sum=0} }' data.dat" \
using (column(2)):xtic(1) with filledcurves x1 t column(2)
```

When I add time in xdata:

> ```
> set xdata time
> set timefmt "%Y%m"
> set xtics format "%b"
> ```

Erros message:

```
Need full using spec for x time data
```

Is the Errors because of my date format? I have googling this and do not have any answer about it. Please give me suggestion about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the script you show, you specify only a single column in the `using` statement (besides the `xtic`). That means, that this value is taken as y-value and the row number is implicitely used as x-value.

When using time data, you must explicitely specify *all* columns which are needed for the plotting style, there is no assumption about what might be the first column. Use:

```
set key below autotitle columnheader
set ylabel "Count"
set xlabel "across time"
set tics front

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y%m"
set xtics format "%b'%y"
set autoscale xfix

plot for [i=10:2:-1] \
"< awk 'NR==1 {print \"year\",$".(i-1)."} NR>=2 {for (i=2; i<=".i."; i++) \
{sum+= $i} {print $1, sum; sum=0} }' data.dat" \
using 1:2 with filledcurves x1 t column(2)
```

Result with 4.6.4:

[image]

I guess you don't want `xtic(1)` if you have time data and specify the x format.

Comment: I also get error while my data more that 12, how I display years for range 3 years?

Comment: Your larger data set works fine with the script I posted, see the updated image in my answer.

Comment: How to I added year in the x-axis i.e jan'11 , apr'12,

Comment: even time format I set timefmt "%Y%m", the x-axis still display full data 01-01-2011

Comment: Or with `set format x "%b'%y"` for a shorter string, see update.

Comment: how to custom the colors of filledcurves?. somehow the default colors are ambiguous. but I do not have idea to change my gnuplot scripts right now.

Comment: You can customize the colors with e.g. `set linetype 1 lc rgb 'dark-violet'; set linetype 2 lc rgb "#009e73"` etc. If you dont' want to redefine the whole color scheme, you could try one of the two scripts `colors_default.gp` and `colors_podo.gp` which should be included in your gnuplot distribution. If you don't have them, you can get them from http://gnuplot.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gnuplot/gnuplot/share/?pathrev=Release_4_6_5. Just use `load 'path/to/colors_default.gp'` at the beginning of your scripts.

Comment: I have copied the colors_default.gp in the same folder with my gnuplot and datafile. but no effect to my graphs. still have the random colors. where is part of my gnuplot script that I should change? beside that I add `load 'colors_default.gp'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55365/discussion-between-indi60-and-christoph).